# Using left join in dpylr to match and fill a data frame R

Tags: r, dplyr, left-join

I have an issue that will no doubt be solved very quickly. I have a master file that contains all possible combinations of stock tickers and managers over a 5 year period - this file is represented by mastera below. I then have 20 separate  files which represent the quarterly holdings of the manager in each of the stocks (for example data frame firsta). I want to modify the quarterly or master data frame so that if a manager has dropped their holding in a stock, or a manager drops off totally I will allocate them a value of 0, otherwise the actual value is used. That way I will have 20 files with consistent dimensions.

I figured the best way to do this was to use left_join from dplyr. The issue I have is that if I use the code below, the new data frame x only contains 0. I guess it is because the figures from firsta do not overwrite. Any help would be appreciated.

```
firsta <- data.frame(APPL = c(612,709,1000, 850, 940), 
            MSFT = c(650,790,100, 80, 910),
            IBM  = c(740,550, 222, 333, 550),
            GOOG = c(0, 1000, 500, 600, 200))

row.names(firsta) <- c("man A", "man B", "man D", "man E", "man f")
```

NB man C has dropped off.

```
mastera <- data.frame(APPL = c(0,0,0,0,0,0), 
            MSFT= c(0,0,0,0,0,0),
            IBM  = c(0,0,0,0,0,0),
            GOOG = c(0,0,0,0,0,0)
            )
row.names(mastera) <- c("man A", "man B", "man C" ,"man D", "man E", "man f")

x <- mastera %>% left_join(first)
```

EDIT - The expected outcome would be something like this. That is to say that the there is a third row, which is Man C being all zero. The x data frame needs to be 4 columns and 6 rows.

```
    x <- data.frame(APPL = c(612,709,0,1000, 850, 940), 
            MSFT = c(650,790,0,100, 80, 910),
            IBM  = c(740,550,0, 222, 333, 550),
            GOOG = c(0, 1000,0, 500, 600, 200))
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I have edited the original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `row/column` indexing in `base R`

```
mastera[row.names(firsta), colnames(firsta)] <- firsta
mastera
#      APPL MSFT IBM GOOG
#man A  612  650 740    0
#man B  709  790 550 1000
#man C    0    0   0    0
#man D 1000  100 222  500
#man E  850   80 333  600
#man f  940  910 550  200
```

---

With `tidyverse`, we could `gather` into 'long' format and then do the join

```
library(tidyverse)
firsta %>% 
    rownames_to_column('rn') %>%
    gather(key, val, -rn) %>% 
    right_join(mastera %>% 
                 rownames_to_column('rn') %>% 
                 gather(key, val, -rn) %>% 
                 select(-val)) %>% 
    mutate(val = replace(val, is.na(val), 0)) %>%
    spread(key, val)%>% 
    column_to_rownames('rn')
#       APPL GOOG IBM MSFT
#man A  612    0 740  650
#man B  709 1000 550  790
#man C    0    0   0    0
#man D 1000  500 222  100
#man E  850  600 333   80
#man f  940  200 550  910
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)
mastera %>%
  t%>%data.frame%>%
  right_join(firsta%>%t%>%data.frame)%>%
  replace_na(list(man.C=0))%>%
  t%>%
  data.frame()%>%
  set_names(names(mastera))

     APPL MSFT IBM GOOG
man.A  612  650 740    0
man.B  709  790 550 1000
man.C    0    0   0    0
man.D 1000  100 222  500
man.E  850   80 333  600
man.f  940  910 550  200
```

in base R, you can do something like:

```
a = t(merge(data.frame(t(mastera)),data.frame(t(firsta)),all.y=T))
a[is.na(a)] = 0
colnames(a) = names(mastera)
a
      APPL MSFT IBM GOOG
man.A    0  612 650  740
man.B 1000  709 790  550
man.D  500 1000 100  222
man.E  600  850  80  333
man.f  200  940 910  550
man.C    0    0   0    0
```

Comment: Thank you for this Onyambu. I did manage another approach (with melt and merge) but I think yours might be easier.